# Error Update Data in Mysql's Column

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sorry asking simple question,

but I really dont know whats the problem.

```
$id = $_POST['id']; //i get the value from form
$query = "UPDATE jewelry SET stock = stock - $quantity WHERE jewelid = '".$id."'"
mysql_query($query);
```

but if I use this code:

```
$query = "UPDATE jewelry SET stock = stock - $quantity"
```

it works normally, but every column is subtracted..so we must use `where`, but if I use `where` like above., it doesn't work..

where is the mistake in my code?

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code. and if that's your real code, it's missing a semi-colon.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry very much sir. i dont know before that we must accept and answer, thanks for your referention, i will do it asap..

Comment: can you add what table looks like

Comment: @rayejoe You're welcome. It also shows everyone that a solution was found and may be tempted to post more answers also. It's best to mark a question as being solved, that way it doesn't remain in the unanswered category.

Comment: `$quantity` is set somewhere and is an integer? This is open to SQL injections as well.

Comment: what my first comment about errors translates to is this. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` and the fact about the missing semi-colon is a parse error right there, IF that is your actual code. @rayejoe there isn't enough in your question for code here. HTML form, connection method, etc.

Comment: @chris85 it is interger type,, it doesnt matter it just my university project.

Comment: Do you get any errors? `UPDATE jewelry SET stock = stock - 1 WHERE jewelid = '1'` seems like it should work to me. I'd put the math bit in parenthesis just for readibility.

Comment: is stock a variable?

Comment: `WHERE jewelid = '".$id."'` is failing you then, and you need to find out why. Something I told you to do, *twice*.

Comment: @chris85 yes, it works, but i doesnt work if i use $quantity and $id , but i must. i am sure something wrong there but i dont know what is the correct one.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, $quantity and $id is making this error, but i dont know what is the correct one.

Comment: @stock is a collumn from my table.

Comment: You need to let us now what the issue is so we can resolve it. Is the `id` coming in. Is `quantity` set correctly. Does the query execute without error but not update anything or is it erring?

Comment: well you're not cooperating here. You've not included your HTML form, you've not told us what those variables are and if they hold values and what type of values, there is far too many uncertainties in order to provide you with a solution. I will pass on this question and you will need to take it up with Jack's answer, seeing someone upvoted it. Good luck @rayejoe I sincerely wish you find your solution. *Cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- thats not i want, not like you think sir.. i dont include my form because thats very crowded on my code.. i have echo $quantity for testing, and its work fine, example $quantity's value is 2 here. and $id = 'PR002' . all fine, whats the problem is the syntax after WHERE, because when i put down WHERE, it work fine.

Comment: Not reproducible, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5cfbb/2.

Comment: `and $id = 'PR002'` - `jewelid` is what "type", varchar, int, other? make sure that there are no whitespaces being introduced anywhere, this including from user input, or in db and `trim()` will take care of that. Do a `var_dump($id);` and show us what results you get. Also var_dump your query. You really should be providing us with a db  schema and its values, because now we're all being led down a very deep "rabbit hole".

Comment: @chris85 what make error is syntax near $quantity and $id .  ".$quantity." or "$id" maybe but i dont know the correct one.

Comment: Are you getting an error, what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = "UPDATE jewelry SET stock = 'stock - " . $quantity . "' WHERE jewelid = " . $id;
```

if the `jewelid` is a int there is no need to add `= '" . $id . "'` just do `= " . $id . "` not single quote needed

Comment: that shouldn't matter. However what does matter is if their column is an int type or not and trying to pass an integer to a varchar for example. MySQL will compensate for the quotes.

Comment: @Jack smith it doesnt work

Comment: @Fred-ii- sure my stock column has int type ..

Comment: what value in $quantity ?

Comment: `$query = "UPDATE jewelry SET stock = stock - ." $quantity '". WHERE jewelid = ".$id."";`

Comment: @VipinJain it is users input, it sure int type..

Comment: @VipinJain sir u give me a bit answer, yeah i must " " in $quantity.. but i add " " like u ask,, but it doesnt work too. any idea?

Comment: From OP: `and $id = 'PR002'` see, it's a string and not an integer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry, why it must interger on $id ? calculation on quantity right ?

Comment: @rayejoe you can't do calculations on a string, not the way you're doing in anyway. Since you state at id is "PR002". I have no idea how to help you out here, because and again; there are too many unknowns. If your form does not imply a specific `method="post"`, forms default to a GET method if there isn't any. You could provide us with a minimal example of what your form looks like, including the db schema.

Comment: @rayejoe try i just edited

Comment: @rayejoe I'd sure like to know why you suddenly accepted this answer. I'm not saying it's wrong, but amidst all the comments we said up there, we have no way of knowing what was the *real/actual* reason as to why it was failing and why it's suddenly working.